Not possible to enable GNOME Shell extensions in Ubuntu 24.04
I have installed Ubuntu 24.04 (not upgraded from an older version) and I have the issue of not being able to enable GNOME Shell extensions. Here are the details of my Ubuntu release:
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release: 24.04
Codename: noble

I installed Extension Manager, and chrome-gnome-shell with:
sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell

In Extension Manager it is possible to install extensions, but not to enable them, as the switches are greyed out. I also tried to download the extensions from the GNOME Shell extensions website. I can download them without any problem, but cannot enable them.
I tried running the following commands but they did not work:
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt install -f

Additionally, I tried uninstalling Extenssion Manager, renaming ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions and removing it, restarting the system and reinstalling Extension Manager with no effect.
Running the following command also does nothing:
gnone-extension enable <extension>

All custom (not system) extensions are affected. All system extensions except one are enabled as they should, as confirmed by:
gnome-extensions list --enabled

The one system extension that is not enabled is Screenshot Capture Protection and shows this error:
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module @ resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/extensionUtils.js:4:0

This extension is Citrix. I have installed Citrix Workspace as it is needed for my employer.
How can I solve this issue?

The issue is most likely related to Citrix Workspace Client and seems similar to this one: Gnome extensions not working after upgrading to gnome-shell 44.2
Tim B said there:

I have the same issue on Ubuntu after installing Citrix Workspace Client with "App Protecting". I couldn't figure out why all the extensions stopped working.
After uninstalling Citrix all the extensions work again.
It seems like you need to install Citrix Workspace without App-Protection:
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive"
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "icaclient app_protection/install_app_protection select no"

sudo debconf-show icaclient
* app_protection/install_app_protection: no

sudo apt install -f ./icaclient_<version>._amd64.deb

I took the steps from citrix' website on howto enable AppProtection during install and changed values from 'yes' to 'no'
It seems like you cannot uninstall App-Protection once citrix is installed with it.

So remove Citrix Workspace Client and you should be able to enable extensions. If you need Citrix Workspace, install it without App-Protection by running the commands suggested in Tim's quote above.

Much of the troubleshooting for this issue took place in chat. You can find the discussion here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/154579/discussion-between-amar-and-henrichg
